# How test URI for equals without parameter order?

Tags: java, uri

Consider a code:

```
URI one = URI.create("http://localhost:8081/contextRoot/main.html?one=1&second=2");
URI second = URI.create("http://localhost:8081/contextRoot/main.html?second=2&one=1");
System.out.println(one.equals(second));
```

And it prints `false`. Is there a way to test URI without URI parameters order?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How do you override `equals()` for a class defined by the Java runtime?  I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: @ajb Wrong choice of words, sorry :-|

Comment: I don't have a complete answer.  I'd extract the query part, then for each URI, use `split` on `"&"` to create an array of parameters, then create a `Set<String>` from each parameter array, then compare the sets for equality.  You'd have to compare the other parts of the URI, either by copmaring each part, or by creating new URI's without the query parts and using `equals()` on those.  I don't know if this last is possible.

Comment: @ajb Don't post an answer until he clarifies, but yes this approach seems sound.

Comment: @ajb - Yes, that is perhaps not the cleanest approach. But it would work. I wonder if there is a library that does this

Answer (score 0):

Unforunately, equals methods of URI/URL objects are not always do, what you are exactly waiting for. That is why, to compare 2 URI with different parameters order (if you think, the order is not important for you), you should use some utility logic. For example, as follows:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    URI one = URI.create("http://localhost:8081/contextRoot/main.html?one=1&second=2");
    URI second = URI.create("http://localhost:8081/contextRoot/main.html?second=2&one=1");
    System.out.println(one.equals(second));
    System.out.println(areEquals(one, second));
}

private static boolean areEquals(URI url1, URI url2) {
    //compare the commons part of URI
    if (!url1.getScheme().equals(url1.getScheme()) ||
            !url1.getAuthority().equals(url2.getAuthority()) ||
            url1.getPort() != url2.getPort() ||
            !url1.getHost().equals(url2.getHost())) {
        return false;
    }

    //extract query parameters
    String params1 = url1.getQuery();
    String params2 = url2.getQuery();

    if ((params1 != null && params2 != null) && (params1.length() == params2.length())) {
        //get sorted list of parameters
        List<String> list1 = extractParameters(params1);
        List<String> list2 = extractParameters(params2);

        //since list are sorted and contain String objects, 
        //we can compare the lists objects
        return list1.equals(list2);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//return sorted list of parameters with the values
private static List<String> extractParameters(String paramsString) {
    List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] paramAr = paramsString.split("&");
    for (String parameter : paramAr) {
        parameters.add(parameter);
    }
    Collections.sort(parameters);
    return parameters;
}
```